# Downloading JSON data from webpage?

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-requests, stock

I am trying to download data from the iex api using python and currently I am to the point where i get the data, but now i want to format it.

basically i get a lot of data which i do not care about, I just want to have the "float" section.

The data should look like this:

Ticker, Float,

AAPL, 4700000000, (something like that)

The code I am using:

```
import requests 

url = "https://api.iextrading.com/1.0/stock/aapl/stats" 

response = requests.get(url).json()

print (response)
```

I would be verry happy if someone could explain me how to do this.

Kind regards

Right now I have the code:

```
import requests 

url = "https://api.iextrading.com/1.0/stock/aapl/stats" 

response = requests.get(url).json()

data = (response['symbol'], response['float'])

import json filename='resp.json'

with open(filename, 'a+') as outfile:
    json.dump(data, outfile, indent=4)

import requests 

url = "https://api.iextrading.com/1.0/stock/tsla/stats" 

response = requests.get(url).json()

data = (response['symbol'], response['float'])

import json filename='resp.json'

with open(filename, 'a+') as outfile:
    json.dump(data, outfile, indent=4)
```

I would like the data to show as:

Ticker, Float,

AAPL, 4700000000,

TSLA, 1700000000,

(Ticker and float do not neceserally have to be placed above, i could do that myself in excel power query anyway).

Comment: Please, improve your question by adding a sample of json, and what you want to extract from it. You said you want to have the "float" section. What do you call a section in your json?

Comment: Get the `'float'` section by its `key`: `print (response['float'])`

Answer (score 1):

You can just treat it like a dictionary. `response['float']` would give you the float. Similarly for any key.

```
import requests
url = "https://api.iextrading.com/1.0/stock/aapl/stats"
response = requests.get(url).json()
print (response['float'])
print(response['symbol'])
```

Output

```
4705473314
AAPL
```

Answer (score 1):

Your code is doing exactly what it should do, if you want a certain part of the json, just access it.

```
import requests 

url = "https://api.iextrading.com/1.0/stock/aapl/stats" 

response = requests.get(url).json()

print(response['float'])
>4705473314
print(response['symbol'])
>'AAPL'

print(response['symbol'], response['float'])
```

to store `response` in a json file, we can do something like this

```
import json
filename='resp.json'

with open(filename, 'w') as outfile:
    json.dump(response, outfile, indent=4)
```

Comment: 1 more question,

If i would like to save the data to a text file, how can i achieve this?

Currently I am using

saveFile = open('Float Data.txt', 'a+')
saveFile.write(text_lines)
saveFile.close()

Comment: @Hoogoo why not save as JSON file?

Comment: i added an example of that

Comment: Thanks for your efforts,

Unfortunately i still have a small issue, when i type in your code i get the response:
File "main.py", line 10
    with open(filename, 'w') as outfile:
       ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax

I will update my origonal post to show the code I am using now

Comment: Alright, so i fixed that issue. Now, I have another one :p

Comment: thats progress, what is it?

Comment: So basically, when I copy this down and change the ticker symbol (from $aapl to $tsla, for example), and change 'w' to 'a+', it will write multiple outputs to the same file.

the problem is that the data is shown below eachother, and i would like to show the data as:

Ticker, Float,

AAPL, 470000000
TSLA, 170000000

Is there a way i could use this to download multiple stocks at the same time, or if i could parse it to a csv where i get something like i mentioned above?